# can not startActivity in doze mode on android oreo and pie

Tags: java, android, android-8.0-oreo, android-9.0-pie

My question is same as below reference: [startActvtiy in Doze mode on Android Pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55776475/startactvtiy-in-doze-mode-on-android-pie)

I develop a call app. After I release to play store, my user complaint that they can not receive call when their phone enter to idle mode. I use below link and step to let my app force to idle mode: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

lock screen
adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle enable
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step ( let Stepped to deep: IDLE )
adb shell am set-inactive packageName true
After above procedure process, I use pixel/piexel3 XL (Android 9) to test the call flow. I send the highest FCM/GCM message (priority=10) by OneSignal SDK, and expect my activity can be start. The test is fail. My activity can be start when phone is in active state. My OneSignal settings is follow the NotificationExtenderBareBonesExample (https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-customizations#section-background-data-and-notification-overriding)

this example describe how to let the app can receive notification without app running. I also try to add the windows flag like below

>

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
    Log.d(this.getClass().toString(),"turn screen on!!!");
    Bugfender.d("onCreate", "turn screen on!!!");
    setShowWhenLocked(true);
    setTurnScreenOn(true);
}

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) this.getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    if (keyguardManager != null) {
        keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, new KeyguardManager.KeyguardDismissCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onDismissError() {
                super.onDismissError();
                Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Keyguard Dismiss Error");
                Bugfender.d("onCreate", "Keyguard Dismiss Error");
            }

            @Override
            public void onDismissSucceeded() {
                super.onDismissSucceeded();
                Log.d(this.getClass().toString(),"Keyguard Dismiss Success");
                Bugfender.d("onCreate", "Keyguard Dismiss Success");
            }

            @Override
            public void onDismissCancelled() {
                super.onDismissCancelled();
                Log.w(this.getClass().toString(), "Keyguard Dismiss Cancelled");
                Bugfender.d("onCreate", "Keyguard Dismiss Cancelled");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I check my log message, my phone try to start the activity but the activity immediately enter destroy state after it create. the log is show below:

> 2019-05-16 19:00:52 +0800 UI android.app.Application.dispatchActivityPaused Activity paused: IncomingCallActivity 2019-05-16 19:00:52 +0800 UI android.app.Application.dispatchActivityCreated Activity created: VideoChatViewActivity 2019-05-16 19:00:53 +0800 UI android.app.Application.dispatchActivityStarted Activity started: VideoChatViewActivity 2019-05-16 19:00:53 +0800 UI android.app.Application.dispatchActivityResumed Activity resumed: VideoChatViewActivity 2019-05-16 19:00:53 +0800 UI android.app.Application.dispatchActivityPaused Activity paused: VideoChatViewActivity 2019-05-16 19:00:53 +0800 UI android.app.Application.dispatchActivityStopped Activity stopped: IncomingCallActivity 2019-05-16 19:00:53 +0800 UI android.app.Application.dispatchActivityDestroyed Activity destroyed: IncomingCallActivity

I have no clue why my activity can not alive after receive push message. Please kindly give me advise

Comment: Were you able to solve that?

Comment: @Ray Chen did you solve this ?